# Antibot spam protection on contact form

Tags: javascript, spam, bots

I`m using this in my contact form for antibot but still i received tons of mails:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
var a = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);
var b = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);      
var c = a + b 
function DrawBotBoot()
{
 document.write("Antibot "+ a + " + " + b +" = ");
 document.write("<input id='BotBootInput' type='text' maxlength='2' size='2'/>");
}    
function ValidBotBoot(){
    var d = document.getElementById('BotBootInput').value;
    if (d == c) return true;        
    return false;

}
</script>
```

Can someone help me and make this to ask for lets say "what is current year" or something like this ?
Thank you

Comment: This is written in JavaScript. Most bots don't execute or even look at JavaScript, which is why it's broken; they simply submit the form with no JS to stop it.

Comment: Use [reCaptcha](http://www.google.com/recaptcha)

Comment: *sigh* Always validate your stuff on the server side...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CAPTCHA to protect yourself from Bots. Something like [reCaptcha](http://www.captcha.net/) will suite your needs. It will much decrease the amount of spam messages to your form.

Answer (score 1):

For someone that doesn't want to use reCaptcha for whatever reason and stay with a basic math question, this can be a solution to limit the number of bots :
http://www.lateralcode.com/basic-math-security/